# For metric space $C^0([0,1])$, a sequence of functions ${x^n}$ is Cauchy in $||-||_1$ norm but not in infinite norm

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

In my text book, it is stated that for a sequence of functions ${x^n}$ in a metric space $C^0([0,1])$, it is Cauchy in $||-||_1$ norm but not in $||-||_\infty$ norm because that would lead to a contradiction.

I am wondering what this contradiction is.

I tried expanding the norm:

$||x^m - x^n||_1 = \int_0^1|x^m-x^n| dx =_{| m<n} \int_0^1(x^m-x^n) dx = \frac{1}{m+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}$, which goes to zero (which is in C) for large m and n, it is thus Cauchy.

but,

$||x^m - x^n||_\infty = lim_{p->\infty} (\int_0^1|x^m-x^n|^p dx)^{1/p} =_{| m<n} lim_{p->\infty} (\int_0^1(x^m-x^n)^p dx)^{1/p}$

I am not really sure how I could get this to show a contradiction, or if it's even the right way to go...

Comment: If it were cauchy (hence convergent) in $L^\infty$, then it would be a sequence of continuous functions converging uniformly. So the limit has to be continuous, and at the same time equal to the point wise limit which is not continuous.

Comment: You should work with $\lVert f \rVert_\infty = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \lvert f(t) \rvert$.